# Azure AD Group Membership vs Direct Members

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an AAD group like below
[image]

What is the difference between having a group as a direct member, and a group membership?

Comment: Don't get the question right now. The "Group memberships" tells you in which groups this group is a member itself. Is this your question?

Comment: Ah, the light bulb just went off.  Yeah, that was it.  Thanks for the switch!

Comment: Saturday huh :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Group memberships" tells you in which groups this group is a member itself.